# i have a pandas dataframe and i want to fill missing value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a pandas dataframe with 2 column.1st column has datatype timestamp and 2nd column consist of values and datatype is  int.

```
df1 frame
1st column            2nd column
2019-06-15 00:00:00     520
2019-06-15 02:00:00     263
2019-06-15 04:00:00     756
2019-06-16 14:00:00     264
2019-06-16 17:00:00     1254
```

i want output like this

```
1st column            2nd column 
2019-06-15 00:00:00     756
2019-06-15 01:00:00     0
2019-06-15 02:00:00     263
2019-06-15 03:00:00     0
2019-06-15 04:00:00     756
         ...
2019-06-16 00:00:00     0
2019-06-16 01:00:00     0
         ...
2019-06-16 14:00:00      264
2019-06-16 15:00:00     0
2019-06-16 16:00:00     0
2019-06-16 01:00:00     1254
         ...
2016-06-16 23:00:00      0
2019-06-15 01:00:00      0
```

that is i want to fill the missing hours values to zero.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Seems like you should be able to create a new DataFrame with the appropriate `index`, or use `reindex` and then `fillna`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `resample` with `fillna`:

```
df.set_index('1st column').resample('H').first().fillna(0)
```

---

```
                     2nd column
1st column                     
2019-06-15 00:00:00       520.0
2019-06-15 01:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 02:00:00       263.0
2019-06-15 03:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 04:00:00       756.0
2019-06-15 05:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 06:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 07:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 08:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 09:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 10:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 11:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 12:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 13:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 14:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 15:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 16:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 17:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 18:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 19:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 20:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 21:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 22:00:00         0.0
2019-06-15 23:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 00:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 01:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 02:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 03:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 04:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 05:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 06:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 07:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 08:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 09:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 10:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 11:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 12:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 13:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 14:00:00       264.0
2019-06-16 15:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 16:00:00         0.0
2019-06-16 17:00:00      1254.0
```

Comment: suppose my first date and time is starting from '2019-06-11 11:00:00' and i want the hours from zero than how it can be done in these .@Erfan

Comment: Thats a different question, please post a new question, put the link here and I try to help you @vishwajeet